# Is it possible for the charge carrier concentration to go down when doping?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Not sure if this makes sense, but if a p-type material is doped with another p-type material, is it possible for the hole concentration to go down, or will it always increase?

Comment: Why do you think that the hole concentration would go down?

Comment: (1) how are you measuring carrier concentrations? (2) I can certainly come up with various scenarios where adding more dopants reduces the carrier concentration.

Comment: @JonCuster I am measuring using a technique called C-V (capacitance-voltage profiling), I'm not sure this is a common technique. I can explain or link this if you would like me to. This allows me to get a value for N. When I doped a p-type material (PTB7) with another p-type (F6TCNNQ). Here's the data just for simplicity: Dopant present= 0% N=1.0e13, Dopant present = 0.01% N= 4.7e15, Dopant present 0.05% N= 7.8e14, Dopant present 0.1% 7.9e14

Comment: @harshit54 This is a result of an experiment, there are more details in my previous comment

Comment: @HelloQuestion Sorry, this is out of my scope of knowledge.

Comment: @harshit54 No worries, thanks for trying!

Comment: @JonCuster I just wanted to add that I thought that this was not possible in reality and is likely a result of poor measurement, or something gone wrong somewhere

Comment: It could be measurement error, sample prep differences, etc. However, it could also be dopant-dopant clustering, dopant-defect (say dopant-vacancy complexes) interactions, and so forth.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you so much, that is incredibly useful. Do you have any suggestions on what measurements could be made to find out if these effects are happening and which of them are happening? I realise that I cannot describe what is going on here with the results that I have, but I can propose ideas for what is happening and suggest ways in which I could find out, of course apart from some unexpected measurement error explaining all of this. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Transport measurements may help. TEM and other materials characterization may help. I'd say the oddball measurement is the one at 0.01%. The plateauing of carrier concentration at 0.05 and 0.1% might make some sense.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you very much for your input, again very helpful.

Comment: @JonCuster Hi, sorry to bother you again about this question. I actually remembered that as part of this work, i did some AFM on different dopant concentrations. It didn't connect in my head that this could be used to identify some of those effects you talked about. 0% dopant: https://www.dropbox.com/s/usmhlfdyb3s3vky/TheARLayou2t.tif?dl=0 0.01% dopant: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nta488c7shupcqt/TheARLayou3t.tif?dl=0, 0.05 dopant: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu1ry41f45p17zs/TheARLayout5.tif?dl=0. I'm wondering if you think this is sensitive enough to rule out for example dopant-dopant clusering?